# Sequence of all but the last elements of a collection for which a predicate is true

Tags: clojure

I’m having trouble writing an elegant `drop-last-by` or `butlast-by` function.

```
(drop-last-by odd? [2 1 9 4 7 7 3])  ; => (2 1 9 4)
(drop-last-by odd? [2 4])  ; => (2 4)
(drop-last-by odd? [9])  ; => ()
```

What I have so far works but seems a little clumsy and I wonder if it can be done in just two or three lines.

```
(defn drop-last-by [pred coll]
  (let [p (partition-by pred coll)]
    (apply concat (if (and (seq p) (pred (first (last p))))
                    (butlast p)
                    p))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Since [`drop-while`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/drop-while) already does basically what you need, and since your current solution is already not lazy, I'd write `drop-last-by` like this:

```
(defn drop-last-by [pred coll]
  (reverse (drop-while pred (reverse coll))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The version below is lazy to the degree permitted by the problem specification:

1. any elements that do not satisfy the predicate are immediately passed through without reading any additional elements from the source;
2. any elements that do satisfy the predicate are passed through as soon as an element that does not satisfy the predicate is read in from the source;
3. any elements that satisfy the predicate and are not followed by further elements that do not satisfy the predicate are dropped.

Additionally, it can be used as a (stateful) transducer; indeed the lazy seq version is implemented in terms of the transducer and `clojure.core/sequence`.

```
(defn drop-last-by
  ([pred]
   (fn [rf]
     (let [xs (volatile! [])]
       (fn
         ([] (rf))
         ([result] (rf result))
         ([result input]
          (if-not (pred input)
            (do
              (reduce rf result @xs)
              (vreset! xs [])
              (rf result input))
            (do
              (vswap! xs conj input)
              result)))))))
  ([pred coll]
   (sequence (drop-last-by pred) coll)))
```

At the REPL:

```
(drop-last-by odd? [2 1 9 4 7 7 3])
;= (2 1 9 4)
(drop-last-by odd? [2 4])
;= (2 4)
(drop-last-by odd? [9])
;= ()
```

Composed with other transducers:

```
(into []
      (comp (drop-while even?)
            (drop-last-by odd?)
            (map #(str "foo " %)))
      [0 1 2 3 4 5])
;= ["foo 1" "foo 2" "foo 3" "foo 4"]
```